# Type 2 error graphical representations

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, inference

What is the statistical meaning of type 2 error in graphical terms. Why it is represented under alternative hypothesis curve not under null hypothesis curve.

Comment: Maybe this post can help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211736/type-i-error-and-type-ii-error-trade-off

Comment: But they haven't told why it is under alternative hypothesis curve.