# Why a false positive is called type I error and a flase negative a type II error?

Tags: terminology, type-i-and-ii-errors, history

I am trying to understand what are the historical reasons behind the choice of the term Type I and Type II error. I think is much more intuitive to use false positive and false negative. These two terms are unintuitive.

Comment: Sequential numbering is fairly common. This is how economists wound up with 5-6 types of the [Tobit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model) models. If it helps, [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/211739/7071) is how I remember the difference.